# AngularJS $http ".then" callback is not firing with ExpressJS and sendgrid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, sendgrid

I have this function in angular

```
controller: function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.sendEMail = function (referal) {
    // console.log('referal: ', referal);

    $http({
      url: '/send-referal',
      method: "POST",
      data: referal
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log('success', response);
      },
      function (response) { // optional
        console.log('error', response);
      });
  };
}
```

Now the `.then` is not executing after.

In the server side in express I have the endpoint like this:

```
app.post('/send-referal', function (req, res) {
  console.log('data: ', req.body);

  var html = "my html template";

  var helper = require('sendgrid').mail;
  var from_email = new helper.Email(req.body.email);
  var to_email = new helper.Email('foo@bar.com');
  var subject = 'Subject for referal form';
  var content = new helper.Content('text/html', html);
  var mail = new helper.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content);

  var sg = require('sendgrid')('api key here');
  var request = sg.emptyRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/v3/mail/send',
    body: mail.toJSON(),
  });

  sg.API(request, function(error, response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    console.log(response.body);
    console.log(response.headers);
  });
});
```

This is the normal example that sendgrid gives you. The function sends the email normally but in client side I don't get any response at all so I could tell the user that the email was sent.

How do I get the `$http` request to fire the `.then` action?

Comment: You don't actually send a response so the client will never get it.  You need to do something with the `res` property to send a response back to the client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to send the response back from the server with `res.json` as below,

```
app.post('/send-referal', function (req, res) {
  console.log('data: ', req.body);

  var html = "my html template";

  var helper = require('sendgrid').mail;
  var from_email = new helper.Email(req.body.email);
  var to_email = new helper.Email('foo@bar.com');
  var subject = 'Subject for referal form';
  var content = new helper.Content('text/html', html);
  var mail = new helper.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content);

  var sg = require('sendgrid')('api key here');
  var request = sg.emptyRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/v3/mail/send',
    body: mail.toJSON(),
  });

  sg.API(request, function(error, response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    console.log(response.body);
    console.log(response.headers);
  });

  // Send the response back to client something like below
  res.json({success:true});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your $http call has some issues. Once you fix them you will find out more about the call and if the backend is fine (which looks fine) this will solve the problem.

Your are passing 2 functions (success and error handler functions) to `then`. You should pass the error function to `catch`. Alternatively you can get rid of `then` and 'catch` and just pass those 2 functions directly to the $http call.

Example fix with then and catch:

```
    $http({
      url: '/send-referal',
      method: "POST",
      data: referal
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log('success', response);
    }).catch(function (response) { // optional
        console.log('error', response);
    });
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed by other answers your response is hanging i.e. unwritten. I suggest you follow @Aruna 's answer to fix the server side.